# File system of SD card

Tags: java, android, filesystems

I don't know how to retrieve file system of SD card on android. How to do it? It shows like directories.

```
final String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();//shows the String name

final File primaryExternalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();//shows directory
```

**The very core** of question:
I have an sd card. I don't know file system. How to know it?

Comment: What do you mean, "retrieve the file system".  Of course you get a directory.  That's what you asked for.

Comment: File system :fat32, etc.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question.

Comment: The only way I know is to parse `/proc/self/mountinfo`  That should give you the type.

Comment: Please, write more detailed information how to know it from this path "/proc/self/mountinfo" to file system